# filtering items from list in df column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new column with values from another column where the column type is a list. I'm struggeling to select only specific values from the said list and not the entire list if the value meets the condition.

More specific I want to create a new column with the values that contain 'critic'. So the result should look like this:

```
ID        LIST_COLUMN                                   NEW COLUMN 
id1       ['moviecritic', 'movie', 'disney']            moviecritic
id2       ['musiccritic', 'Metallica', 'rock']          musiccritic
id3       ['bookcritic', 'young adult', 'literature']   bookcritic
```

I've tried following, but it returns a ValueError (Length of values (0) does not match length of index (3))

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['id1', ['moviecritic', 'movie', 'disney']],['id2',['musiccritic', 'Metallica', 'rock']],
        ['id3',['bookcritic', 'young adult', 'literature']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','LIST_COLUMN'])
        
        
df['NEW_COLUMN'] = [x for x in row.df['LIST_COLUMN'] if 'critic' in x]
```

Comment: And what if `'moviecritic'` and `'bookcritic'` were in the same list?

Comment: This will never be the case, so you don't need to take that into account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `explode` the list then filter to the values you want and assign back (it will align on Index, which `explode` preserves). Since you will never have more than 1 value with 'critic' in it this will work.

```
s = df['LIST_COLUMN'].explode()
df['new_column'] = s[s.str.contains('critic')]

    ID                            LIST_COLUMN   new_column
0  id1           [moviecritic, movie, disney]  moviecritic
1  id2         [musiccritic, Metallica, rock]  musiccritic
2  id3  [bookcritic, young adult, literature]   bookcritic
```

---

If possibly multiple matches, you will need to somehow aggregate along the original Index, for instance you can `str.join`:

```
df['new_column'] = s[s.str.`contains('critic')].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're very close, but another loop is needed to traverse the lists themselves, which we can do with `next` and short-circuit:

```
df["NEW_COLUMN"] = [next(seq for seq in a_list if "critic" in seq)
                    for a_list in df["LIST_COLUMN"]]
```

to get

```
    ID                            LIST_COLUMN   NEW_COLUMN
0  id1           [moviecritic, movie, disney]  moviecritic
1  id2         [musiccritic, Metallica, rock]  musiccritic
2  id3  [bookcritic, young adult, literature]   bookcritic
```

To provide a default value in case of no match in a row, you can change the `next` as:

```
next((seq for seq in a_list if "critic" in seq), None)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine to, have accepted the other answer as solution since I find it a little bit more straightforward